# How do I ensure that when a user enters a value into all values once a value is entered inton one?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Hope the title of my thread makes sense.

I have seven gridview controls, starting with ID of gridview1.

Please see code below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtspousename" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtspouseaddress" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Income">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtspouseincome" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" Visible="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd2" runat="server" Text="Add"
                            OnClick="ButtonAdd2_Click" CssClass="grvAddButton" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In the example code above, there are three form fields, **txtspousename**, **txtspouseaddress**, and **txtspouseincome**.

A user can click the submit button without entering any values into any of the fields and that's fine because not all gridview controls require values.

However, if a user enters value, say, into txtspousename, user must be required to enter values into the remaining two form fields.

Failure to do so should raise an error that the remaining two form fields must have a value.

The jquery script I am using below is not doing that.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is the script below.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                //Attach click event to each button in gridview
                $("#GridView1").find("input[type='submit']").click(function (event) {
                    var isValid = true;
                    //Find the selected button tablerow(tr)
                    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
                    if (tr.length > 0) {
                        //check if txtspousename textbox is empty or not
                        if ($.trim(tr.find("input[type='text']").val()) != '') {
                            //Loop through other textboxes and check if its empty or not
                            tr.find('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
                                if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                                    isValid = false;
                                }
                            });
                            //If empty then display the message
                            if (isValid == false) {
                                alert("Please enter values on other textboxes as well");
                                event.preventDefault();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
        </script>


///View Source:

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(".grvAddButton").click(function(event) {
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

  var $textboxes = $row.find("input[type=text]");
  var totalTextboxCount = $textboxes.length;
  var $emptyTextboxes = $textboxes.filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
  });
  var emptyTextboxCount = $emptyTextboxes.length;

  //If there are textboxes filled out, but not all of them...
  if (emptyTextboxCount > 0 && emptyTextboxCount !== totalTextboxCount) {
    alert("Please enter values in all textboxes in the row.");
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {                    //DEMO PURPOSES ONLY
    alert("Success!");        //DEMO PURPOSES ONLY
    event.preventDefault();   //DEMO PURPOSES ONLY
  }
});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <form method="post" action="./disclosures.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="survey_form" class="form a">


    <div class="bs-example">
        <p><span id="lblResult" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;"></span></p> 
     <div style="margin-left:35px;margin-top:0px;">


            <!-- All user textboxes for input here -->
            <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">Name, title, and email address of employee filling this form</span><br /><br />
           <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <div class="input text">
                <label for="lblEname"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color:#000000;">Employee Name</span><span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                 <input name="txteName" type="text" id="txteName" placeholder="Employee name..." class="form-control" style="width:200px;" />
                <span id="RequiredFieldValidator2" style="font-weight:bold;visibility:hidden;">*</span><br />
                 </div>
                 </td>
                <td>
                 <div class="input text">
                <label id="lblTitle"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color:#000000;">Your title</span><span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                <input name="txttitle" type="text" id="txttitle" placeholder="Employee title..." class="form-control" style="width:200px;" />
               <span id="RequiredFieldValidator3" style="font-weight:bold;visibility:hidden;">*</span><br />
               </div> 
               </td>
                <td>
                 <div class="input text">
                 <label id="lblEmail"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color:#000000;">Your email address</span><span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                <input name="txtemail" type="text" id="txtemail" placeholder="Employee email..." class="form-control" style="width:200px;" />
               <span id="RequiredFieldValidator4" style="font-weight:bold;visibility:hidden;">*</span><br />
                </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <div class="input text">
                 <label id="lblEmpID"><span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color:#000000;">Your employee Id</span><span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
                <input name="txtEmpID" type="text" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;txtEmpID\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" id="txtEmpID" placeholder="Badge ID..." class="form-control numeric" style="width:100px;" />
               <span id="RequiredempidValidator1" style="font-weight:bold;visibility:hidden;">*</span><br />
                </div>
                </td>
                <td>

             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
            <br /><br />

          <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">Name and address of income source greater than $1,000.00 (No comma (,)  or period(.), eg 1000)</span><br /><br />             
          <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="Gridview1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Address</th><th scope="col">Income</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                    <input name="Gridview1$ctl02$txtsourcename" type="text" id="Gridview1_txtsourcename_0" placeholder="Name..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">
                    <input name="Gridview1$ctl02$txtsourceaddress" type="text" id="Gridview1_txtsourceaddress_0" placeholder="Address..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">

                     <input name="Gridview1$ctl02$txtsourceincome" type="text" id="Gridview1_txtsourceincome_0" placeholder="Income...(example: 1000)" class="form-control txtsourceincome numeric" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td>
                 <input type="submit" name="Gridview1$ctl02$ButtonAdd" value="Add" onclick="return ValidateEmptyValue();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;Gridview1$ctl02$ButtonAdd&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="Gridview1_ButtonAdd_0" class="grvAddButton" />
                </td><td></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
            <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">Name and address of income source of spouse greater than $1,000.00 (No comma (,)  or period(.); Example 1000)</span><br /><br />              
            <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="grvspouse" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Address</th><th scope="col">Income</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                    <input name="grvspouse$ctl02$txtspousename" type="text" id="grvspouse_txtspousename_0" placeholder="Name..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">
                    <input name="grvspouse$ctl02$txtspouseaddress" type="text" id="grvspouse_txtspouseaddress_0" placeholder="Address..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">

                     <input name="grvspouse$ctl02$txtspouseincome" type="text" id="grvspouse_txtspouseincome_0" placeholder="Income...(example: 1000)" class="form-control txtsourceincome numeric" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td>
                 <input type="submit" name="grvspouse$ctl02$ButtonAdd2" value="Add" onclick="return ValidateSPEmptyValue();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;grvspouse$ctl02$ButtonAdd2&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="grvspouse_ButtonAdd2_0" class="grvAddButton" />
                </td><td></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
             <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">Name and address of divident(s) with income greater than $1,000.00 (No comma (,)  or period(.), eg 1000)</span><br /><br />              
            <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="grvDiv" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Address</th><th scope="col">Income</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                    <input name="grvDiv$ctl02$txtdividentname" type="text" id="grvDiv_txtdividentname_0" placeholder="Name..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">
                    <input name="grvDiv$ctl02$txtdividentaddress" type="text" id="grvDiv_txtdividentaddress_0" placeholder="Address..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">

                     <input name="grvDiv$ctl02$txtdividentincome" type="text" id="grvDiv_txtdividentincome_0" placeholder="Income...(example: 1000)" class="form-control txtsourceincome numeric" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td>
                 <input type="submit" name="grvDiv$ctl02$ButtonAdd3" value="Add" onclick="return ValidateDivEmptyValue();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;grvDiv$ctl02$ButtonAdd3&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="grvDiv_ButtonAdd3_0" class="grvAddButton" />
                </td><td></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
            <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">Name and address of Reimbursement(s) with income greater than $,000.00</span><br /><br />              
            <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="grvReim" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Address</th><th scope="col">Income</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                  <input name="grvReim$ctl02$txtReimbursename" type="text" id="grvReim_txtReimbursename_0" placeholder="Name..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">
                    <input name="grvReim$ctl02$txtReimburseaddress" type="text" id="grvReim_txtReimburseaddress_0" placeholder="Address..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">

                  <input name="grvReim$ctl02$txtReimburseincome" type="text" id="grvReim_txtReimburseincome_0" placeholder="Income...(example: 1000)" class="form-control txtsourceincome numeric" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td>
                 <input type="submit" name="grvReim$ctl02$ButtonAd4" value="Add" onclick="return ValidateReimEmptyValue();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;grvReim$ctl02$ButtonAd4&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="grvReim_ButtonAd4_0" class="grvAddButton" />
                </td><td></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
          <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">Honoraria from a single source</span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="popover" title="Honoraria Definition" data-trigger="focus" data-content="A payment given to a professional person for services for which fees are not legally or traditionally required."><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" style="color:#ffffff"></span></button>
            <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="grvHon" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" scope="col">Honoraria</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                    <input name="grvHon$ctl02$txthonoraria" type="text" id="grvHon_txthonoraria_0" placeholder="Honoraria from a single source..." class="form-control" style="width:800px;" />
                </td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
            <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">Name and address of Gift(s) with income greater than $500.00</span><br /><br />             
            <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="grvGift" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Address</th><th scope="col">Income</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                    <input name="grvGift$ctl02$txtgiftname" type="text" id="grvGift_txtgiftname_0" placeholder="Name..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">
                    <input name="grvGift$ctl02$txtgiftaddress" type="text" id="grvGift_txtgiftaddress_0" placeholder="Address..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">

                     <input name="grvGift$ctl02$txtgiftincome" type="text" id="grvGift_txtgiftincome_0" placeholder="Income...(example: 500)" class="form-control txtgiftincome numeric" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td>
                 <input type="submit" name="grvGift$ctl02$ButtonAdd6" value="Add" onclick="return ValidateGiftEmptyValue();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;grvGift$ctl02$ButtonAdd6&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="grvGift_ButtonAdd6_0" class="grvAddButton" />
                </td><td></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
              <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">Name and address of Organization(s) with income greater than $1,000.00 (No comma (,)  or period(.), eg 1000)</span><br /><br />            
              <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="grvOrg" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Address</th><th scope="col">Income</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                    <input name="grvOrg$ctl02$txtorgname" type="text" id="grvOrg_txtorgname_0" placeholder="Name..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">
                    <input name="grvOrg$ctl02$txtorgaddress" type="text" id="grvOrg_txtorgaddress_0" placeholder="Address..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">

                 <input name="grvOrg$ctl02$txtorgincome" type="text" id="grvOrg_txtorgincome_0" placeholder="Income...(example: 1000)" class="form-control txtsourceincome numeric" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td>
                 <input type="submit" name="grvOrg$ctl02$ButtonAdd7" value="Add" onclick="return ValidateOrgEmptyValue();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;grvOrg$ctl02$ButtonAdd7&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="grvOrg_ButtonAdd7_0" class="grvAddButton" />
                </td><td></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
              <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;color:#000000;">Name and address of Creditors(s) with income greater than $7,500.00 (No comma (,)  or period(.), eg 1000)</span><br /><br />            
            <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" id="grvCred" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <th align="left" scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Address</th><th scope="col">Income</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>
                    <input name="grvCred$ctl02$txtcreditorname" type="text" id="grvCred_txtcreditorname_0" placeholder="Name..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">
                    <input name="grvCred$ctl02$txtcreditoraddress" type="text" id="grvCred_txtcreditoraddress_0" placeholder="Address..." class="form-control" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td align="left">
                     <input name="grvCred$ctl02$txtcreditorincome" type="text" id="grvCred_txtcreditorincome_0" placeholder="Income...(example: 7500)" class="form-control txtcreditorincome numeric" style="width:250px;" />
                </td><td>
                 <input type="submit" name="grvCred$ctl02$ButtonAdd8" value="Add" onclick="return ValidateCredEmptyValue();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;grvCred$ctl02$ButtonAdd8&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="grvCred_ButtonAdd8_0" class="grvAddButton" />
                </td><td></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

 </div></div>
 <table width="200" border="0" style="margin-left: 450px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td> <input type="submit" name="btnNext" value=" Review Form " onclick="BtnClick();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;btnNext&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="btnNext" class="btnNext" /></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: what you want is to  remove the title and edit it to say something like `how do I validate the 3 mandatory fields on my form` something like that also `Why do you think you need jquery to do textbox validation` ?

Comment: Point well taken. Thanks

Comment: @MethodMan It's a bit more than that. More like "All or none" validation. OP, you're using `#Gridview1` in your jQuery, but ASP renders client-side ID's much differently than that. Without digging too much into your JS yet, first try putting `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your Gridview (*unless you've already declared this as a default in the Web.Config or something along these lines*)

Comment: Thank you. Adjusted as recommended.

Comment: Asp.net has some `CustomValidators` that can be used

Comment: Please do `console.log($("#Gridview1"));` and let us know whether it returns `undefined` or an actual element.

Comment: I do not want to use the custom validators because as stated  in my original post, not all fields require validation.

For instance, a user can enter values into gridview1 but may not need to enter any values into gridview2., etc

Comment: @Kenny The code I provided should *replace* your code inside the `<script> $(function () { ......... }) </script>` handler - where you have it now, the code is being executed before the page loads, therefore the elements it's looking for aren't on the page yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that this line is not finding anything:

`$("#GridView1").find("input[type='submit']")`

---

When ASP controls like Gridviews render on the page, they are assigned unique ID's like `cphPlaceholder_ct100_Gridview1`. For this reason, it's likely that your selector `#Gridview1` is actually not finding any elements. To force your controls to render with the ID you've assigned to them, you can add the property `<asp:Gridview ...` **`ClientIDMode="Static"`** `...>`.

Alternative methods would be to retrieve the generated client ID by doing `$("#<%= Gridview1.ClientID %>")` or just using a unique class instead.

---

I also believe you can simplify your jQuery quite a bit to something like this instead, but perhaps it's just personal preference.

```js
$(".grvAddButton").click(function(event) {
  var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

  var $textboxes = $row.find("input[type=text]");
  var totalTextboxCount = $textboxes.length;
  var $emptyTextboxes = $textboxes.filter(function() {
    return !this.value;
  });
  var emptyTextboxCount = $emptyTextboxes.length;

  //If there are textboxes filled out, but not all of them...
  if (emptyTextboxCount > 0 && emptyTextboxCount !== totalTextboxCount) {
    alert("Please enter values in all textboxes in the row.");
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {                    //DEMO PURPOSES ONLY
    alert("Success!");        //DEMO PURPOSES ONLY
    event.preventDefault();   //DEMO PURPOSES ONLY
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" class="grvAddButton" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" class="grvAddButton" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**A more complete example including multiple tables and red input highlights can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ods3v2h3/).**

Comment: this solution works if we are adding another row.

That's great but we would like to be able to use the submit button and capture the event for each gridview control.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean. The code above will work for any submit button with class `grvAddButton` in any gridview, validating whichever row was clicked.

Comment: @Kenny I've added HTML to provide a complete example.

Comment: @Kenny And, for sake of proving multiple-gridview support, please check out [this expanded example](https://jsfiddle.net/ods3v2h3/) as well.

Comment: your script  works here as posted when I used it on my code, alert keeps popping "Success" whether data is filled or not.

Comment: Then you'll need to post your rendered HTML rather than the ASP controls. When your page loads, do a View Source, and copy the HTML of the table into your question. It's much easier to debug the client-side code when you can see what you're looking for :)

Comment: I have posted the source. It starts from //View Source.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's going to work on the gridview, but you can try using a custom field validators for each control like this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="validator" runat="server"
        ErrorMessage="Error to display"
        Text="*"
        Display="Dynamic"
        ControlToValidate="txtspousename"
        ValidateEmptyText="False" ClientValidationFunction="validateFields" />
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateFields(s,args){
        // Evaluate conditions like.
        // Get elements id's like: <%= txtspouseaddress.ClientID %
        args.IsValid = true;
    }
</script>
```

You can also do validations on the server side (using OnServerValidate on the CustomValidator).

Hope it helps.
Good luck!